# Multiple SELECTs in Psycopg2 or SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I want to execute multiple SELECT statements at once, as I do with

```
echo "SELECT * FROM x; SELECT * FROM y;" | psql
```

so that I send something to database only once, and receive all the result at once too.

It would be perfect to do it with SQLAlchemy, but it seems to be unsupported (isn't it?).

I thought I might reimplement some parts of SQLAlchemy to get that feature, but I didn't find the solution for this problem in psycopg2 too - executing two queries separated with a semicolon gives the results of the last query only.

So, is it possible to do it with SQLAlchemy (which would be perfect) or with psycopg2 (which would be fine too)?

Comment: If results of these queries are compatible, maybe a `UNION` would apply?

Comment: Why do you want to do this in one round trip instead of two?  Do note that when you issue two statements to `psql`, it *does* go to the database twice, just as if you had issued two `connection.execute()` calls.

Answer (score 4):

Bartosz - I am facing a similar problem and came across your question from two years ago. One way to get around this might be to use Postgres json support. What you can do is construct two select queries that convert row output into json, union them together and then decode in python or whatever language you are using. This gets the data in one round trip to the database.

You could use other json constructors that postgres has available, such as `row_to_json`:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html

```
SELECT to_json((a, b, c))
FROM x

UNION ALL

SELECT to_json((d, e, f, g, h, i))
FROM y
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score -1):

In your example, run two independent queries. This is not a feature of alchemy or psycopg. Just pure python:

```
query1 = s.query(x).all()
query2 = s.query(y).all()
out = query1, query2
```

Comment: That is not the solution to my problem. I know how to get result of two queries. I meant to do it in such a way, that data is sent to Postres once and received from it once. I wrote it clearly in the question.

Comment: In your example, run two independent queries, writed in one line. If you want write it in one line on python, can do so: print map(lambda z: s.query(z).all(), [x, y])

Comment: It is not about how many lines it takes, but how many times does my application send SQL to database server and how many times it receives results. My problem was answered in @IfLoop's comment - it is not possible to do it in one trip.